# How to recover grub after Windows installation

Tags: ubuntu, debian, grub2, gnu

Usually when we install Windows after installing GNU/Linux, we usually lose the Grub. Which is the best way to recover grub when we lost grub or what are the possible different ways.

Comment: Related: [How can I prevent Windows from overwriting GRUB when using a dual-boot machine](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68581/how-can-i-prevent-windows-from-overwriting-grub-when-using-a-dual-boot-machine)

Answer (score 3):

You need to boot system using LiveCD of ubuntu and run below command to install grub :

```
sudo grub-install /dev/XXX
```

above command will install grub and it also Keep windows bootloader NTLDR into grub , then you can choose any one OS while boot.

`/dev/XXX`  this is your HDD where ubuntu installed (eg: grub-install /dev/sdb).

Please refer below link for more information :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Answer (score 1):

Late but the problem is as recent as it can be. I managed to avoid creating an up-to-date Live CD/USB stick to issue the [recommended range of commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68587/293199). From within **Windows 10 Command Prompt (not  PowerShell!) with admin rights**, I used:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
```

for EFI Secure Boot. You can normally use

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

More details and screenshots [here](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/88823-bcdedit-says-set-command-specified-not-valid.html) and [here](https://techwiser.com/fix-grub-after-windows-10-upgrade/).

Comment: At least for Windows 7 didn't work.

Comment: Hi, I see, W7 was the one back then, so which errors did you get if any? Unfortunately, the guides I used assume that W10 is installed. I added that detail.

Comment: No errors. But on restart nothing changed.

Comment: Hmm, maybe settings like `bootmgr` might have changed from W7 to W10. See e.g. https://neosmart.net/wiki/bcdedit/#BCDEdit_on_Windows_7 Maybe try `bcdedit /?` to find out. Moreover, are you using EFI at all? Is there a `grubx64.efi` file in the partition?