# Triple boot: Windows 10, 7, and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

So my main HD is a windows 10 and I decided to install Ubuntu as a dual boot, and everything was fine. I could choose which one to boot to in the menu on start up, either windows 10 or ubuntu.

Today I have tried to install windows 7 aswell, to have a triple boot. The problem is now, my computer always boots up windows 7 and I don't have the option to choose any other OS. Could someone please help me? The internet on the windows 7 doesn't work either so I feel like I'm completely screwed over.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent Windows from overwriting GRUB when using a dual-boot machine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68581/how-can-i-prevent-windows-from-overwriting-grub-when-using-a-dual-boot-machine)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is bootloaders, where to write them, and how to keep "the one" from being over written.

Personally I'd run Ubuntu as the only bare-metal OS and use Virtualbox for the Windows systems.  Of course, you can do the same iwth Windows 10, and virtualize Win7 and Ubuntu.

To get back your Ubuntu and Win10 bootloader download the Ubuntu ISO, boot it, open a terminal, mount your Ubuntu / partition, chroot to it, and re-run the grub-install.

```
sudo mkdir /rescue-system
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /rescue-system
```

Note - change /dev/sda5 in the previous line to match whatever partition your / partition really is

```
sudo mount --bind /dev/ /rescue-system/dev
sudo chroot /rescue-system
mount -t proc none /proc
mount -t sysfs none /sys
mount -t devpts none /dev/pts
grub-install /dev/sda
```

Then simply exit out of the chroot and reboot.